# On platforms where pthread_t is numeric, is 0 guaranteed to be an invalid value?

Tags: c++, pthreads

`pthread_t` (as returned by `pthread_self()`) is an opaque type, but on some platforms is actually numeric, for example `typedef`ed to `unsigned long`. On these platforms, is `0` an invalid `pthread_t` value? What about `-1`?

Comment: I'd argue that this isn't a duplicate, because I'm asking about platform-specific behaviour and not the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wanted a value that was either a `pthread_t` or invalid, I'd use a `boost::optional<pthread_t>` or `std::optional<pthread_t>` from C++1y.

This has very little overhead (bytes), expresses what I want (this value may or may not be a `pthread_t`), and doesn't rely on platform-specific behavior.

Comment: Hmm yes, using `optional` or a flag is probably the best general-purpose option. But I'm specifically limiting my usage of `pthread_t` to platforms where it is numeric, precisely because it allows me to use it without any overhead (I'm putting it into a `std::atomic`).

Comment: @Cameron `std::optional< std::atomic< pthread_t > >` -- I guess that doesn't let you atomically make the `pthread_t` invalid, or change it from invalid to valid atomically.

Comment: I hadn't thought of inverting it! (Nice trick!) Unfortunately I would need to put the `optional` inside the `atomic` (I'm building a lock-free hash table with thread IDs as keys, and I need to know whether a given slot in the table is free or not based purely on its value, and swap it all at once). I suppose if `sizeof(optional<pthread_t>)` was 64-bits I could just use a double-wide CAS operation, though.